# Decimal KeyPad for iphone in hybrid app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, decimal

I have a number field with no restriction on amount that can be entered. Business requirement is to show a decimal keypad. We are using input type="number". This works fine in android. I tested in Edge and this works like a charm. But the default keypad comes up in iphone. I did search on internet before coming here. But I could not find a way out. There is no existing custom cordova plugin for this as well. 
FYI- We are using ionic to build this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think Showing decimal keypad is even possible in cordova iOS.

> i finally wrote a new plugin
>   https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard

[image]

Comment: but this solution is for only ios...what about android?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

or

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*">
```

Comment: I would suggest the first one, second one doesn't work with android.

Comment: This works fine for numbers 0-9. But if you have any decimal numbers such 12.56, this is not going to work in iphone.

Comment: Then it's not possible to show the dot or comma. If you use input type tel, there is a "Pause" button that is displayed as a , when pressed, but it will be confusing for the user. There is a native keyboard plugin in progress that will help you once it's released